Parse Pope's "they humbly take upon content"
From Alexander Pope's Essay on Criticism II.305–310:

Others for language all their care express,
And value books, as women men, for dress:
Their praise is still—"the style is excellent":
The sense, they humbly take upon content.
Words are like leaves; and where they most abound,
Much fruit of sense beneath is rarely found.

The sense of this passage is clear; now help me parse the style. ;)
The bolded phrase above clearly means something like "The sense, they assume satisfactory without sufficiently examining it." But how do we get there from the words "take upon content"?

Is it that they humbly take the sense "upon contént"? Can one "take something upon content", "take sth. upon angry", "take sth. upon delighted", etc?

Is it that they humbly "take upon" the sense (and are contént)? Can one "take upon sth."?


I see this "KJV Dictionary" website defining content as "satisfaction without examination" and giving Pope's line as their citation; but not only does that seem circular, it still doesn't tell me how to parse the line: "The sense, they humbly take upon satisfaction-without-examination" doesn't make any more syntactic sense to me.

This is an obsolete idiom, according to the OED: To take upon content means "to accept without question or examination." Content here means "acceptance of conditions or circumstances, acquiescence". The OED gives the historical range 1646–1752 which includes the time of Pope.
It relates to other uses of content as a noun meaning "Satisfaction, pleasure; a contented condition." This derives either from the verb or adjective content.
The use in the idiom is similar to something like "take on trust" or "take upon trust", with "on" and "upon" often used synonymously. On, "7a—used as a function word to indicate reason, ground, or basis (as for an action, opinion, or computation)", Merriam-Webster.
See: Oxford English Dictionary, s.v. “content (n.2),” March 2024, https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/1014332688.

A moment ago I found this excellently, if sparsely, annotated version which includes exactly that gloss: "take upon content" = "take on trust". :)

In other words, "I'll take your word for it that it says something deep."

To paraphrase "take on trust" we could say "to accept, sight unseen", and that notion is borne out by the concluding couplet, which gives the example of scant fruit hidden beneath abundant leaves:

The sense, they humbly take upon content.
Words are like leaves; and where they most abound,
Much fruit of sense beneath is rarely found.

